# As of today, is there still not any secure way of using Twitter sign in in client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, authentication, oauth

A few years ago, the Anywhere lib let us do signin with Twitter.

Now that is deprecated, and the only way of logging into twitter from client side JS is by using OAuth 1.0b which needs the private key to be placed in public JS code, which is completely unsecure.

Is there any other way currently available of achieving Twitter login in client side only JS?